# Implement forgot password functionality

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I need help with my Ionic 2 app. I'm using angularfire2 to connect with firebase: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

My app is working, saving users, and managing authentication. Now I need to know how to implement the "Forgot password" functionality.

I can't see any method for doing that with this library, but in the firebase official docs yes. But I don't know if I can include it in an Ionic 2 project.

Someone can help me?

Thank's so much in advance!

Ivan.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the firebase.auth library for this.

Use this you can use `firebase().auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(res => {});` to access this functionality.

You can use it wherever you want, beeing it inside the .ts file of the page where the user'll call for a 'forgot password' method or a provider.

So do this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export class MyCurrentPage {

  constructor(){}

  forgotPass(){
    // SOMETHING TO INTERACT WITH THE USER, THEN...
    firebase().auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(res => {});
  }
}
```

I don't know if AngularFire is still installing firebase with it, if not you need to install it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AngularFire2 and you want to put it in a service. This should do. It will return an observable.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    firebase: any;

    constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) fb: any) {
        this.firebase = fb;
    }

    forgotPassword(email: string) {
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email));
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, this could be useful if someone uses angularfire2. In the end I used the native firebase library that mentions the tutorial provided by @Sagar Arora. I did not know that there was already that library in my project. LOL rookie errors

Comment: Glad this helps :)